# Android - How to send multiple checked values data to php server?

Tags: java, php, android, android-checkbox

I'm working Android sdk platform. Working of application - When a user selects multiple checkboxes and on the basis of checked values, the user would receive notifications. My question - how do i send checked values data to php server? What should be the approach in mainactivity.java? In android app, how will I store DATA & send it to my PHP server?

Comment: How do you want to store the data? Should it be persistent or not? There are many ways to send data as well. What is important to you?

Comment: From your multiple questions, sounds like you need to go thru a good android tutorial. https://developer.android.com/samples

Comment: You can use a network library for configuration server connection. You can search Retrofit . There are a lot of tutorials about it.

Comment: Of course persistent. As I explained, a user selects checkboxes and on the basis checked values, the user receive notifications. I've a sql query in php file. I want to get checked values and send it to php server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to be more specific in your question, 
Example, how do I send checked values data to php server? You can send those values as json

```
{
  "checkboxes": [
    {"checkbox_1": false},
    {"checkbox_2": true},
    {"checkbox_3": true},
    {"checkbox_4": false}
    ]
}
```

What should be the approach in mainactivity.java?

1. read the status of every checkbox:

   ```
   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          // save value here
       }
   });
   ```
2. Create a list values or create immediately a json to send to the php server
3. Then use [Retofi2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to connect to the server
4. To create persistence data you can use something simple like **SharedPreference** or more complex like **Room** or Repository pattern ..

Divide your question into as many parts as possible

Comment: Since I'm not from Android porgramming background, I work on machine learning projects. I'm beginner in Android sdk.

Comment: I found this tutorial. https://www.blueappsoftware.in/android/blog/send-data-from-android-device-to-php-server/

Comment: Ok I see, may I suggest this https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial, try something like this, and then go step by step, first try to connect with your server